# I am getting an error when trying to use melt() on a dataframe containing Dates

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I'd like to melt the `dataframe` so that in one column I have dates and in a second I have username as the variable and finally the value.

I'm getting this error:

> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

and while I understand the error I'm not exactly sure how to get around it.

A small sample of the data is:

```
structure(list(created_at = structure(c(14007, 14008, 14009, 
14010, 14011, 14012), class = "Date"), benjamin = c(16, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), byron = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cameronc = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), daniel = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), djdiaz = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), gene = c(16, 77, 64, 38, 72, 36), joel = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2), kerem = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sophia = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), SuperMoonMan = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("created_at", 
"benjamin", "byron", "cameronc", "daniel", "djdiaz", "gene", 
"joel", "kerem", "sophia", "SuperMoonMan"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("cast_df", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try converting the `created_at` variable into a character vector. `melt` also doesn't seem to like the `cast_df` class, but I had success by resetting the class to just `data.frame`. Like so:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$created_at <- as.character(df$created_at)
library(reshape)
melt(df)
```

Comment: i'm giving wkmor1 the check mark because he got it first and did solve the problem. That said Marek big thanks for helping me better wrap my head around what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

You error is caused by `rbind` used in `melt`, which is consequence of wrong data to melt. I don't know how you create your `cast_df` `data.frame`, but it missing attributes (`idvars` and `rdimnames`) which are required by `melt.cast_df`.

That is why [wkmor1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831319/i-am-getting-an-error-when-trying-to-use-melt-on-a-dataframe-containing-dates/2831632#2831632) solution works, `melt.data.frame` don't need this arguments. And without converting `Date` to `character` it can be done as:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
melt(df, id="created_at")
```